# Variables are not passed in the email template

Tags: laravel, email, laravel-5, markdown

I'm having this method in my controller

```
public function update(UserUpdateRequest $request)
{
        $request->user()->update([
            'name' => $request->username,
        ]);

        Mail::to($request->user())->send(
            new UserUpdated( $request->user() )
        );

        return redirect()->route('account.index');
}
```

So when the user updates the username an email is send

```
public $user;

/**
 * Create a new message instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct(User $user)
{
    $this->user = $user;
}

/**
 * Build the message.
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function build()
{
    return $this->markdown('emails.user.updated');
}
```

And this is the email template

```
Hi {{ $user->username }},

We would like to inform you that your username has been updated successfully. 

If this action wasn't done by you, you need to contact with our support.
```

But this is throwing an exception in the queues

> ErrorException: Undefined variable: user in /storage/framework/views/

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You can't declare it just like that: $this->property = $something;

Comment: But its pretty much the same as in the documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/mail#view-data

Comment: Can you try via the `with` method?

Comment: Already tried it, but no luck. I dd($user) and dd($this->user) inside the constructor and the user data are passed, however they are not available in the template, which is weird

Answer (score 0):

Try passing it to the `view` via `with` method and make `user` variable protected:

```
protected $user;

public function build()
{
    return $this->view('emails.user.updated')->with(['username' => $this->user->username]);
}
```

And then you can access it like `{{ $username }}` in your view.

Comment: Already tried it, but no luck. I dd($user) and dd($this->user) inside the constructor and the user data are passed, however they are not available in the template, which is weird

Comment: Are you sure you used `view` instead of `markdown`?

Comment: Yes I followed the steps from the documentation

Answer (score 0):

Try this and then access the $user in your view

```
public function update(UserUpdateRequest $request)
{
    $request->user()->update([
        'name' => $request->username,
    ]);

    $user = $request->user();

    Mail::to($request->user())
        ->send(new UserUpdated($user));

    return redirect()->route('account.index');
}
```

You can't send $request directly to you email template may this is the reason why you are not able to access the $user